# set stack level tags in a cloudformation template- not in a nested stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

A little confused about how to do this or if its possible.

THis is not a nested stack. I want to set tags in my CF template that apply to all resources in the template. AWS::CloudFormation::Stack resource can do that, but I don't need/want a nested stack i just have one stack and one template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use command `deploy` with `--tags`:

```
aws cloudformation deploy \
   --template-file template.yaml \
   --stack-name MyStack \
   --tags Key1=Value1 Key2=Value2
```

[Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy/index.html):

> **--tags** (list) A list of tags to associate with the stack that is created or updated. AWS CloudFormation also propagates these tags to resources in the stack if the resource supports it. Syntax: TagKey1=TagValue1 TagKey2=TagValue2 ...

Comment: Is there a way to specify this from the CF template rather than CLI?

Comment: In SAM you can do it with "globals", but applies only for some resources: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-template-anatomy-globals.html

Answer (score 1):

You can solve that with a kind of a workaround.
You can create another CF template that will include only the "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack" resource.
In the parameters, provide the tags that you want, and in the "TemplateURL" property, provide the URL of a template that specifies the stack that you want to create as a resource. 
Note that the template must be stored on an Amazon S3 bucket, so the URL must have the form: 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/.../TemplateName.extension

For more details:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#cfn-cloudformation-stack-templateurl